# Issue : Need to use Media Store Api or No Access to Files - Google Play Console Rejection when target sdk was 30

Tags: java, android, store, playback

Hi Programming fellas

I have uploaded our apk to google play console but they have rejected our apk and mentioning use Media Store Api for camera and gallery.

My App has already implemented and use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and work fine on all android version

The problem arise  when I changed target sdk to 30 and submit app.These are the permission which I used for READ WRITE operation.

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have attached screen shot of rejection from google play too.Previously I have tried to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but still our app was rejected

If any body encounter with this issue kindly post a solution for this

Thanks ...

[Play Console Rejection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyyBG.png)

[Play Console Rejection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRhzg.png)

Comment: Your wish is already full filled. Solutions have been posted here already several times as many encountered the same.

Comment: What is the core functionality of your app?

Comment: Can you share a link for those problems ? @blackapps

Comment: Core Functionality of our app is messaging but there is not any feature available to be check mark while submitting our app ... 
@SagarMaiyad

Comment: For messaging, they will not allow you to use this permission. Check permitted uses list provided by google.

Comment: It is now pretty unclear for which action  you need prrmissions. Noting needed for camera and gallery.

Comment: i have same issues they reject my app twice because i have used managed external storage permission and my core functionality is playing media for dowloading files i have to use these permission but they r rejecting it how is it possible .

Answer (score 1):

In Android 11, the way to access external storage has changed a bit.

Source:
[Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

In my case, I've solved my problem like this:

1. I added file_path.xml in path src/main/res/xml

   [FilePath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzLWU.png)
2. I've used **getExternalFilesDir** for get file in the device storage.

Before:

```
val mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Ticket_" + date + ".jpeg"
```

After:

```
 val mPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/Ticket_" + date + ".jpeg"
```

I hope help you :)